# Keep JQuery UI Dialog Open after Post inside Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, modal-dialog

I am currently developing an application using ASP.Net MVC 5.  The application uses the JQuery UI library for showing modal dialogs.

The problem I am encountering is that on one of my modal dialogs I require the user to select a product from a drop down list (within the dialog) and on the users selection I want to reload the dialog however have it populated based on the on the users selection (without closing  the dialog).

Can anyone offer me any pointers in how to achieve this.

Regards,

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reload the page because if page reload dialog will close so you can make a simple partial view and when user selects a value from dropdownlist just pass value to partialview and then load that partialview in dialog with the help of ajax call in jquery this will prevent page load and closing of dialog also.

**Edit :-**

A Demo :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dropdown1").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
                url: "/MyController/getdata",
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'html',
                data: { dropval : $(this).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                   $("#div1").html('');
                   $("#div1").html(data);

            });
    });
});
```

Controller(MyController) :

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult getdata(string dropval)
{
//bind model here
return PartialView("mypartialview",model)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Exception, are you able to post an example of the view as well please.

Comment: @StuartFerguson..code for view is entirely depends on your application i just post required code and rest is depends on your app..partial views are just as simple views just do as same way as you do for views..

Comment: @StuartFerguson...above code is enough i think to guide you .. i don't know your complete scenario but above code is more then enough to guide you...thanks..

Comment: I have implemented the code as you have put above and this is now hitting the controller on the drop down change however my modal form is not being populated with the model data I am returning, can you explain what the 

success: function (data) {
                   $("#div1").html('');
                   $("#div1").html(data);" 
section does as I am assuming that's where i am going wrong.

Comment: @StuartFerguson..yes with that code the html inside div with id div1 will first removed and new html coming from controller will replace the html..you just have to do is that instead div1 just put the container div id which you want to replace with new html..

Comment: Not quite lol, getting an Internal Server Error on the call, just looking into why at the moment.

Comment: sorted the error, I had a typo in the partial view name :|, I have one other question, is there a way to pass a value from the model class up with the drop down change ?

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest is to not reload the dialog, intead you can clear and refill the dialog through ajax call.You can do an ajax call to get action of the controller and returns the partial view 
in success method, update the html of the dialog box as per user.